# Newsletter box is too wide

Tags: bug, site-redesign

[image]

The box that entices users to subscribe to the newsletter is too wide for its container. It needs a `box-sizing: border-box;` CSS rule to actually fit.

My configuration: W8, Firefox Quantum 61.0.2 (64-bit)

Comment: And no, I'm not subscribed. I never read the thing anyway :P

Comment: Same behavior for me on Safari 11.1.2/macOS 10.13.6

Comment: Am I suspecting correctly that this is now obsolete given the new site design?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft That is my suspicion as well, but a confirmation by SE would have been nice :/

Comment: @Vincent: Well, do you still observe the problem?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Yes.